# Oracle 11g - How to execute multiple line in merge statement?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, merge, row, procedure

I am using `merge into` statement now, but it does not fit requirement. Current code like ...

```
create or replace procedure 
  mv_data
is 
begin
  merge into WORK w
    using (select * from IF_WORK where batch = 0) i
      on (w.token in (select token from IF_WORK where batch = 0))
    when matched then
      update set 
        w.area = i.area
        , w.cust_id = i.cust_id
        , w.status = i.status
        , w.changed = sysdate
      where w.token = i.token
      -- I want to put "update IF_WORK set batch = 1 where work_id = i.work_id" here. Exception handling also.
    when not matched then      
      insert 
        (
        token, area, cust_id, status)
      values
        (i.token, i.area, i.cust_id, i.status)
      -- I want to put "update IF_WORK set batch = 1 where work_id = i.work_id" here. Exception handling also.
      ; 

  update IF_WORK set batch = 1;      
  commit;

  exception 
    when others then rollback;  
end;
```

And follows are what I concern ...

1. In current code, it runs `for` loop and than update all. Need to individual control. (I have to update IF_WORK table for only success data)
2. Location of `exception` statement. I want to rollback or commit for each row, not for all. However, for now it will rollback all.

So I have tried to change code to one `merge` procedure and procedures which handles single row. But I know can not use procedure at `when matched then`.

How can I implement this? Is there any good statement/method ?
Thanks.

`P.S` Since I have worked with Java so long, the code I provided looks like the follow in Java.

```
/* This is something I wanted
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String s : aList){
            try{
                * INSERT data !!! *
            }catch(Exception e) {
                * UPDATE data !!! *
            }
        }
    }
    */

    // Something I implemented for now
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            for(String s : aList){
                * INSERT data !!! *
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            * UPDATE all !!! *
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this hasn't been answered yet, I thought I would partially answer it.

It's not easy to fully answer it, because I do not know all the details of your database design.

However, in general, you can use an Oracle Implicit cursor, to start looping through a set of data.

You can still use the Merge statement, to now insert or update, dealing with only one row.

Some pseudo-code is below:

```
create or replace procedure 
  mv_data
is 
begin

FOR ifwork IN (
  SELECT area, 
      cust_id, 
      status, 
      token,
      work_id,
      whatever_your_primary_key_column_is
  FROM IF_WORK
  WHERE batch=0
)
LOOP
merge into WORK w
  using (select ifwork.area, ifwork.cust_id, ifwork.status, ifwork.token, ifwork.work_id from dual) i
  ...////rest of your MERGE statement here

//update if_work set batch = 1 where whatever_your_primary_key_column_is=ifwork.whatever_your_primary_key_column_is
    END LOOP;



END;
```

Comment: Thanks. It was great help. I put procedure in `begin ~ end;` block which located inside of `loop` and put exception statement into that. So I can handle exception by row units. thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve this with Robert's answer.

I made 2 procedures (those do not have `exception` statement. handle those in caller procedure)

1. insert original table and the other
2. update original table and the other

than I call this inside of `loop` statement

```
create or replace procedure 
  mv_data
is 
begin
  for if_row in (
    select 
      *
    from IF_WORK
    where batch = 0
  )
  loop 
    begin
      procedureA(data ..., work_id);
      exception
        when dup_val_on_index then
          update_both(data ..., work_id);
        when others then rollback;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

I hope this will help others like me :D

- additional advices are always welcomed